# Change span text with active link text

Tags: jquery, function, menu, responsive

I've been trying to figure this problem out with no success so far, I don't know jquery so any help with be appreciated. I'm using bootstrap to build my web page, my sidebar turns to a second mobile menu, it already displays they way I want it to and I also added the active class to my web page successfully and a function to close the menu once I select an item from the list, the only thing I couldn't accomplish is when I select a sport from the list I want the title span "Generales" to change text to the active link text in this case "Soccer" or the current active link.
My HTML:

```
<div class="left-navigation">
  <button class="btn collapse-toggle visible-xs">
    <span class"menuTitle">Generales</span>
  </button>
  <div class="list-group-collapse" id="side-category-menu-collapse">
      <a href="#generales" class="list-group-item active">General</a>
      <a href="#soccer" class="list-group-item">Soccer</a>
      ><a href="#football" class="list-group-item">Football</a> 
      <a href="#baseball" class="list-group-item">Baseball</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery for the active and collapse menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-group-item").click(function () {
    $(".list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).addClass("active");   
  });
});
$(function(){ 
 var navMain = $(".list-group-collapse");
 navMain.on("click", "a:not([data-toggle])", null, function () {
     navMain.collapse('hide');
   });
});
```

Jquery I tried to use but I haven't had any luck:

```
$('.left-navigation a').click(function(){
    console.log('hiding');
    $('.menuTitle').click();
    var title=$(this).find(‘.list-group-item').html();
    console.log(title);
    $('.menuTitle').html(title);
});
```

Here's an image of my current menu and what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEaqC.jpg

Sorry in advance for any grammar mistakes since English is not my first lenguage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  $(".list-group-item").click(function () {
    $(".list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $("#selected-menu:first-child").text($(this).text());
   
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-navigation">
  <button id="selected-menu" class="btn collapse-toggle ">
    <span class"menuTitle">Generales</span>
  </button>
  <div class="list-group-collapse" id="side-category-menu-collapse">
      <a href="#generales" class="list-group-item active">General</a>
      <a href="#soccer" class="list-group-item">Soccer</a>
      <a href="#football" class="list-group-item">Football</a> 
      <a href="#baseball" class="list-group-item">Baseball</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! this worked too! thanks a lot for the help @Omi

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-group-item").click(function () {
    $(".list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).addClass("active");   

    $("span:first-child").text($(this).text());
     $("span:first-child").val($(this).text());
  });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/DSGxz/1726/

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked just the way I wanted, I just had to replace
`$("span:first-child").text($(this).text());
$("span:first-child").val($(this).text());` 
with:
 `$(".deportes").text($(this).text());
$(".deportes").val($(this).text());`
Because span:first-child was also replacing the back button from my first menu with the active text...

Comment: my mistake, not `.deportes` it was actually `.menuTitle` I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:  `$(this).text()`  to get the link text.

So:

```
$(‘.left-navigation a').click(function(){
    console.log('hiding');
    $('.menuTitle').click();
    var title=$(this).text();
    console.log(title);
    $('.menuTitle').html(title);
});
```

Comment: Hi, Jessica, I think we're close, I'm getting this on the console: http://imgur.com/a/YBa9L but my span title doesn't change yet...

Comment: @AnelBarco Did you write it just like Jessica did? You've got `var title=$(this).find(‘.list-group-item').html();` You need to get rid of the `.find(".list-group-item")`

Comment: @AnelBarco show us your new code if that isn't working? It should work...

Comment: yes I got rid of that part of the code but it wasn't working, I copied exactly what Jessica wrote: http://imgur.com/a/Pc1DW but the title wasn't changing: http://imgur.com/a/r8hhn